# classic asp on iis 7 - getting things to work without adding a foldername/ to all includes and paths in an application

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, asp-classic

I recently got this huge application written in classic asp that came to me in a zip file called `ivx`. I'm on IIS 7 running on Windows 7 64 home premium on my laptop.

What I've now done is unzipped `ivx` to `inetpub/wwwroot`. So it's now `c:/inetpub/wwwroot/ivx/`

The problem is, the entire application contains includes and other things pointing to the root (my guess is this was pulled down directly from the server).

```
<!--#include virtual = "/main/indexfunctions.asp" -->
<!--#include virtual = "/common/adminverify.asp" -->
```

To get things working, I'll have to add `/ivx` to each and every path in the application. I know I can get thing going if I unzip all files to the root directory, but I cannot do that since there are other files there.

How can I make this whole thing work without having to add the current folder name to all the paths in the application? Is there a setting somewhere in IIS or elsewhere that'll let me do this?

Comment: I *think* you need to create a new 'application' in IIS Manager that points to the ivx folder. Been a while since I used classic ASP...

Comment: You're right. That kinda works now.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not horribly misunderstanding, aren't the folders just pointing to the site root? It's a relative path, so `<!--#include virtual = "/main/indexfunctions.asp" -->` will look for indexfunctions.asp in the ivx/main folder. Am I totally mistaken? I don't really get the question.

Comment: It'll only work if I change it to `/ivx/main/indexfunctions.asp`

Comment: I think that's because you need to turn the ivx folder into an application within IIS manager, otherwise the root is still the website root and not ivx.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is a virtual website, where you access the website either via a custom hostname (like ivx.yourmachine.local -- add that to your hosts file) or via a port number (like localhost:8080). read [Understanding Sites, Applications, and Virtual Directories on IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis) and then look at [How to: Create and Configure Virtual Directories in IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)